# Default radio button is checked but styles to it not working

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I have two radio buttons, No and Yes. By default no is checked. I have css that styles the checked elements. But by default the styles only work if you physically check it. I want to style it right of page load without have to select it. Currently I am stumped. Thanks for your help

**HTML**

```
<div class="split">
    <input id="contact-no" type="radio" name="contact" value="No" checked="checked">
    <label for="contact-no">No</label>
</div>
<div class="split">
  <input id="contact-yes" type="radio" name="contact" value="Yes">
  <label for="contact-yes">Yes</label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.am-form input[type="radio"] + label:hover, .am-form input[type="radio"]:checked + label{background: rgb(239,58,65);}
```

**What it looks like on page load:**
[image]

**What It should Look like on page load and after you select it:**
[image]

Comment: Why don't you just have JavaScript change it?  Or, just use a separate class for the red version, and change to that?

Comment: @durbnpoisn why would you use javascript when you don't need to? btw it works fine for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8rw31e5p/1/)

Comment: This seems to work for me on page load in FF: http://jsfiddle.net/nh7vz01h/

Comment: agree with @blcook223 : http://codepen.io/tunecino/pen/eNXKLd
what is the full CSS you are using for this ?

Comment: its working for me, Please check below code http://jsfiddle.net/2keh5xkw/ Please provide more information like CSS/ HTML code and browser which you are targeting.

Comment: @billyonecan.  My reasoning is that CSS may not be 100% reliable on all browsers.  JS could resolve that in cases where it's not working.  This, especially since it's specified that a click is involved in making the change.

Comment: I have added the full rule to my question and also added it at the bottom of my stylesheet so it is not overridden but still no luck. I am using a wordpress site and have enqueued that stylesheet to appear on that page only. Also adding !important did not work either.

Comment: You have loads of duplicate ids on the page. If you correct all those, does the problem persist?

Comment: I removed all the multiple ID's and it still does not take effect. Their are multiple ids because there are four separate parts of the form but only one is ever visible at once. The would you like to be contacted section will only appear once, so wouldn't be a duplicate.

Comment: Done some trouble shooting, Mr Lister 3 your advice was correct in a way. It has something to do with the multiple id's and the fact that they are display none. As when I remove the display none on the container it works off the bat.

Comment: Solved it, I had to update the id's as well as the name attributes all to be different. and it seemed to solve the problem. Thanks everyone for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had multiple hidden section with the same name/id, so I juts had to customize each one.

```
<div class="split">
  <input id="ns-contact-no" type="radio" name="ns_contact" value="No" checked="checked">
  <label for="ns-contact-no">No</label>
</div>
<div class="split">
    <input id="fs-contact-yes" type="radio" name="ns_contact" value="Yes">
    <label for="fs-contact-yes">Yes</label>
</div>
```

further down and hidden:

```
<div class="split">
  <input id="bs-contact-no" type="radio" name="bs_contact" value="No" checked="checked">
  <label for="bs-contact-no">No</label>
</div>
<div class="split">
    <input id="bs-contact-yes" type="radio" name="bs_contact" value="Yes">
    <label for="bs-contact-yes">Yes</label>
</div>
```